# How to override a method of a ruby gem for certain conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to override one of the private methods of a gem only when certain conditions are met.

I would like to use this method only if a certain condition is met else use the gem's method.

```
module Net
  class FTP
    def makepasv
      if condition
        @sock.peeraddr[0] == 'AF_INET' ? parse229(sendcmd('EPSV')) : parse227(sendcmd('EPSV'))
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't this work?

Comment: It shouldn't because if you just open a class, you completely overwrite the current implementation and it's not available under `super`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `prepend` the class being overriden and then use the conditional. This way your module will be the last in the ancestors chain and will be able to call `super` in order to use default behaviour

e.g.

```
module Override 
  def to_s(*) 
    if self == 'a'
      "===a===" 
    else 
      super 
    end
  end 
end
String.prepend(Override)

[9] pry(main)> String.new("a")
=> "a"                                                                                                            
[10] pry(main)> String.new("a").to_s
=> "===a==="
[11] pry(main)> String.new("b").to_s
=> "b"
```

Comment: You forgot the bit where you prepend this to the String?